# Show that $\int^1_0 \frac{\tanh^{-1} x}{x} \ln [(1 + x)^3 (1 - x)] \, dx = 0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am looking for a nice slick way to show

> $$\int^1_0 \frac{\tanh^{-1} x}{x} \ln [(1 + x)^3 (1 - x)] \, dx = 0.$$

So far I can only show the result using brute force as follows.
Let 
$$I = \int^1_0 \frac{\tanh^{-1} x}{x} \ln [(1 + x)^3 (1 - x)] \, dx.$$
Since
$$\tanh^{-1} x = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left (\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right ),$$
the above integral, after rearranging, can be rewritten as
$$I = \frac{3}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2 (1 + x)}{x} \, dx - \int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 + x)}{x} \, dx - \frac{1}{2} \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x)}{x} \, dx.\tag1$$
Each of the above three integrals can be found. The results are:
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2 (1 + x)}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \zeta (3).$$ For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795867/evaluation-of-int-01-frac-log21xx-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316745/how-to-evaluate-int-01-frac-log21xx-mathrm-dx).
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 + x)}{x} \, dx = -\frac{5}{8} \zeta (3).$$
For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085699/evaluate-int-01-dfrac-ln-1-x-ln-1-xx-dx). And
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x)}{x} \, dx = 2 \zeta (3).$$
For a proof of this last one, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882695/find-int-01-frac-ln21-xx-dx).

Thus (1) becomes
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\tanh^{-1} x}{x} \ln [(1 + x)^3 (1 - x)] \, dx = \frac{3}{8 } \zeta (3) + \frac{5}{8} \zeta (3) - \zeta (3) = 0,$$
as expected.

Comment: what about the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$?

Comment: Your integral is \begin{align}\int^1_0\frac{\ln\left(\frac{16x}{(1+x)^4}\right)\ln x}{1-x^2}\, dx\end{align}. \begin{align}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1-x^2}\, dx\end{align} is not so easy to compute.

Comment: The integrand here in fact has an antiderivative that can be expressed in terms of trilogs, dilogs and elementary functions using the integration formula found in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439117/simplifying-a-certain-polylogarithmic-sum-in-two-variables). This expression isn't quite what most people would describe as "nice", but it certainly could be much worse. The alternative ways of solving the definite integral used in the answers provided below are admittedly slicker. OTOH, having the antiderivative opens the door to computing more general integrals.

Comment: What's the point for the bounty?

Comment: I tested something actually and in the same time to bring attention, as it was mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sf I = \frac12 \int^1_0 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x} \ln ((1 + x)^3 (1 - x)) dx=\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{(a-b)(3a+b)}{x}dx$$
Where we denoted $\sf a=\ln(1+x)$ and $\sf b=\ln(1-x)$.
Now we're going to use the following algebraic expression: $$\sf (a-b)(3a+b)=(a+b)^2+2(a-b)^2 -4b^2$$
Which is obtainable easily by combining the following expressions:
$$\sf a^2=\frac12(a+b)^2+\frac12(a-b)^2 -b^2,\quad ab=\frac14(a+b)^2-\frac14(a-b)^2\tag 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \sf 2I=\int_0^1  \frac{\ln^2\left(1-x^2\right)}{x}dx +2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x}dx-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1-x\right)}{x}dx$$
Now we put $\sf x^2=t$ in the first part and $\sf \frac{1-x}{1+x}=t$ for the second one to get:
$$\sf 2I=\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-t)}{t}dt+4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t^2}dt-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-t)}{t}dt$$
$$\sf =-\frac72\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt+4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t^2}dt=-\frac72\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt+\frac72\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt=0$$

---

Above we used that:
$$\boxed{\sf \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}dx=\frac78 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}$$
And we can show this in two steps. First:
$$\sf {\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}\overset{x\to x^2}=8\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}dx=4{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}dx$$
$$\sf \Rightarrow (1-4){\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}=-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}dx\Rightarrow \boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}dx=\frac34 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}$$
But we also have that:
$$\sf \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}dx=\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx+\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x} dx $$
$$\sf =\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx+ \frac38\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx=\frac78 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx$$

---

**Generalization.** In a similar fashion we can deal with the following integral:
$$\sf I(m,n,q,p)=\int_0^1 \frac{[m\ln(1+x)+n\ln(1-x)][q\ln(1+x)+p\ln(1-x)]}{x}dx$$
Like from above we will keep $\sf a=\ln(1+x)$ and $\sf b=\ln(1-x)$. Thus we can write the numarator as:
$$\sf f=(ma+nb)(qa+pb)=mqa^2+(mp+nq)ab+npb^2$$
Using $(1)$ again we obtain:
$$\sf f=\left(\frac{mq}{2}+\frac{mp+nq}{4}\right)(a+b)^2+\left(\frac{mq}{2}-\frac{mp+nq}{4}\right)(a-b)^2+(np-mq)b^2$$
Furthermore we can write:
$$\sf \int_0^1 \frac{(a+b)^2}{x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}dx=\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx$$
$$\sf \int_0^1 \frac{(a-b)^2}{x}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{x}dx=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}dx=\frac74\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx$$
$$\sf \Rightarrow I(m,n,q,p)=\left(\frac{mq}{8}-\frac{5}{16}(mp+nq)+np\right)\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx$$
$$=\boxed{\sf \left(\frac{mq}{4}-\frac{5}{8}(mp+nq)+2np\right)\zeta(3)}$$

Comment: The generalization is really interesting.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}J=\int^1_0 \frac{\tanh^{-1} x}{x} \ln [(1 + x)^3 (1 - x)] \, dx\end{align}
Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,
\begin{align}J&=\int^1_0\frac{\ln\left(\frac{16x}{(1+x)^4}\right)\ln x}{1-x^2}\, dx\\
&=4\ln 2\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}\,dx-4\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Define on $[0;1]$ the function $R$ by,
\begin{align}R(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{1-t^2x^2}\,dt
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}K&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&=\Big[R(x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{(1-t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln 2\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln t}{(1-t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dx\right)\,dt-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{(1-t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt-\\
&\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1-t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln 2\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\right)-\\
&\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx\right)\\
&=2\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt-K+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t}\,dt
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}K&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{1}{8}\left[\ln^2 t\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\right]_0^1+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\boxed{J=0}\end{align}
**NB:**

It's easy to deduce that,
\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1-x^2}\,dx=\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\pi^2\ln 2\end{align}